# How to show that $M:=\{(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3 \,\,∣\,\,a^3+b^3+c^3−3abc=1\}$ is not a compact space?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-numbers, differential-topology, geometric-topology

> How to show that $M:=\{(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3 \,\,∣\,\,a^3+b^3+c^3−3abc=1\}$ is not a compact space?
>   I know that for proving that space is not compact, it must be not closed or not bounded or  (both) not closed and not bounded, but I want a hint how to show this?

Comment: Compare with the simplest case: $M:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \,|\, x^2+y^2-2xy=1\}$ or $M:=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2 \,|\, xy=1\}$. why these are not compact as a topological space?

Answer (score 3):

since $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$
so let's choose $a\to 0, b=-c$, we have $a(a^2+3b^2)=1$
or $3b^2=\frac1a-a^2$, so b is unbounded when $a\to 0$

Comment: thank you, now I understand more.